# HowTo define soname in Code::Blocks

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, codeblocks, versioning

I have created a shared library with Code::Blocks under Linux and now I need to update it to a newer version and I want/need to increment its version.

If I were to use command line I would use a parameter like -Wl soname my_lib.so.2.0.1 but cannot find how to do it under Code:Blocks IDE

Any ideas/help?

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project **Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**
enter, e.g.

```
-Wl,-soname=my_lib.so.2.0.1
```

Then OK out and build.

Comment: thnx, I've been looking for it so long